# How to access a file browser opened by a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, modal-dialog

I am writing a C# WinForms application that fills a form automatically on an existing website.

Let's consider http://tinypic.com/ as an example to illustrate my problem.

When the user clicks the Browse button, a file browser dialog opens as a modal dialog. In my case, the modal window is opened from code and I own the form and the WebBrowser control.

How can I access this modal window programmatically and paste/enter my filename into it ?

Comment: You can use findwindow and sendkey to simulate a user clicking an copy pasting to enter the text.

Comment: Surely there must be a simpler way as my Form is both the parent and owner of the modal dialog. Right ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know particularly, but I do believe its possible (even if you have to hook the OS)

You might want to check TwebstLib for such functionality